# RabbitMQ-MassTransit ReceiveEndPoint not able to listen to the Queue in .net core web APIs

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using RabbitMQ MassTransit for service bus implementation in my .Net core solution. I have created a queue by the name log.service. After lot many efforts I was finally able to push the messages in the queue and can see them in management tool but when I am listening to the same queue in another microservice project, I am unable to do so. I have pushed the messages in the bus from Authentication service and want to log the event in Logging service. Please help!
Here is my authentication-StartUp.cs

```
var buildr = new ContainerBuilder();
        buildr.RegisterType<LoggingCommandConsumer>();
        buildr.Register(c =>
            {
                return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
                 {
                     var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
                      {
                          h.Username("guest");
                          h.Password("guest");
                      });

                     sbc.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                     sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "log.service", e =>
                                   {

                                       e.Consumer<LoggingCommandConsumer>();

                                   });
                 });

            })
            .As<IBusControl>()
            .As<IBus>()
            .As<IPublishEndpoint>()
            .SingleInstance();

        buildr.Populate(services);
        ApplicationContainer = buildr.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
```

Here is my logging-StartUp.cs:

```
 var buildr = new ContainerBuilder();
        buildr.RegisterType<LoggingCommandConsumer>();
        buildr.Register(context =>
            {
                var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                 {
                     var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
                       {
                           h.Username("guest");
                           h.Password("guest");
                       });

                     cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "log.service", e =>
                                             {


                                                 e.Consumer<LoggingCommandConsumer>();

                                             });

                 });
                return busControl;
            })
           .SingleInstance()
            .As<IBusControl>()
            .As<IBus>();

        buildr.Populate(services);
        ApplicationContainer = buildr.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
```

Here I am starting the Bus in both the StartUp.CS

```
 var bus = ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IBusControl>();
        var busHandle = TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.StartAsync());
        lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => busHandle.Stop());
```

Here I am sending the message to end points from authentication controller:

```
    var sendToUri = new 
  Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/log.servicebind=true&queue=log.service");
        var endPoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(sendToUri);

        await endPoint.Send<ILoggingCommand>(new
        {
            XCorrelationId = "asd",
            M4SId = "M4SId",
            Host = "asdasd",
            Level = "Level",
            Time = "2019-01-02T07:06:43.722Z",
            Message = "Message",
            Other = "Other"
        });

        return Ok();
```

When I try to get the above message in log.service bus in rabbitMQ management tool, I am able to do so...but not able to listen it in logging-startup.cs

Answer (score 2):

Your endpoint has a queue defined by `"log.service" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` but you send messages to the `log.service` queue.

I don't really see the point of adding the guid to the endpoint address, what are you trying to achieve?

if you define your endpoint as `cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "log.service", ep => <configuration>` it should work. You need to uncomment your consumer.

Comment: I did uncomment my consumer and did without guid as well but it is still not working. I commented the consumer after getting frustrated as consumer wasn't working. stuck for a week now.

Comment: have used without guid...used guid because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573721/disable-round-robin-pattern-and-use-fanout-on-masstransit
was hitting and trying everything I could find on internet but no luck

Comment: Well, I think the docs is a more reliable source of information http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html#connecting-a-message-consumer

Comment: I have been through docs, I have been through each and everything available over the internet. I am even able to push the messages in the queue, it's just that there is nothing which could help me in consuming. I am doing everything as per the docs and info available. But it is not working. :(

Comment: another thing, so today I tried consuming queue in the same project..it got consumed. But it did not work if I tried consuming in StartUp.cs file of the different project...which is my primary aim.

Comment: The same project uses the same endpoint. Have you removed the guid from the endpoint name? Can you post the updated code?

Comment: See..I have update StartUp.cs for authentication project and now this queue is getting consumed...but if I try to consume it from Logging then again no luck. I just cant seem to find what is going wrong....again adding guid was just a try and I removed it after it didn't work.

Comment: Anything on this?

Comment: @DeepakYadav well, we use tens of ASP.NET Core services with MT on RMQ without any issues. Since I can't see your full code, it is hard to say what the issue is.